# How can i change my form so that the Game property of Enigma is now filled?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

When i try to add an enigma, i need it to be linked to the corresponding game (Professor Layton series), so i made a select input with items corresponding to the different games added to the database. However, when submitting, it doesn't seem to be filling up the required Game field of the current enigma. As i am new to ASP dotnet, any help is appreciated.

view part :

```
@model ProfessorLayton.Models.Enigma

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Create";
    Game game = (Game)ViewData["Game"]!;
}

<h2>Add an enigma to the current list of enigmas</h2>

<hr />
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form asp-action="Create">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Name" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Name" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Name" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Content" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Content" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Content" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <br>
            Chose the game in which this enigma is in :
            <div class="form-group">
                <select asp-for="GameId" class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.GameId"></select>
                <span asp-validation-for="GameId" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <br>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Ajouter l'énigme" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

@section Scripts {
@{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}
}
```

controller part :

```
 //POST: enigma/Create
    public async Task<IActionResult> Create()
    {
        var enigma = await _context.Enigmas
            .Include(g=>g.Game)
            .Include(s=>s.Solution)
            .ToListAsync();
        var availableGamesQuery=from g in _context.Games select g;
        var availableGames=availableGamesQuery.ToList();
        ViewData["Enigma"]=enigma;  
        ViewData["GameId"]=new SelectList(availableGames,"Id","Title")  ;                      
        return View();
    }
    

    //Méthode d'action pour l'ajout d'une enigme
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("Id,Name,Content,GameId")] Enigma enigma,List<Game> games)
    {
        // Apply model validation rules
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            _context.Add(enigma);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }
        else
        {
        // At this point, something failed: redisplay form
        // var allErrors = ModelState.Values.SelectMany(v => v.Errors.Select(b => b.ErrorMessage));
        // return Json(new {allErrors});
        return View(enigma);
        }
        
    }
```

i tried to look up for info, but it always seem overly complicated, so i did not think it was any of a solution.
The comment at the end of the code allowed me to see what the error was with the form, which is the necessity for the game field to be filled up.

Answer (score 0):

You may use `.NET 6`/`.NET 7`.  From .NET 6 the **non-nullable property must be required**, otherwise the ModelState will be invalid.

To achieve your requirement, **the first way** is you can remove `<Nullable>enable</Nullable>` from your project file(double-click the project name or right-click the project to choose Edit Project File).

**The second way**, you can initialize the model like below:

```
public class Enigma
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string? Name { get; set; }
    public string? Content { get; set; }
    public int GameId { get; set; }
    public Game Game { get; set; } = new Game();  //change here...
}
```

**The third way**, you can add ? to allow nullable:

```
public class Enigma
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string? Name { get; set; }
    public string? Content { get; set; }
    public int GameId { get; set; }
    public Game? Game { get; set; }      //change here...
}
```